# Filtering the Xth element in a row?

Tags: string, filter

For example, I want to get **only the 3rd element** in each row when I call:

```
xinput --list --short|grep "slave  pointer"
```

I get the output:

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ite-cir)           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I would like to get only the names like "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad", ...

I saw somewhere a solution with awk and print somehow, but isn't there a simpler solution to achieve that **without** `awk` or `perl` or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gawk *is* pretty simple for this kind of thing but OK, you can also use `cut`:

```
xinput --list --short|grep "slave  pointer" | cut -f 1
```

That will also include the leading space and `↳` characters. If you need to get rid of those, try this:

```
xinput --list --short|grep "slave  pointer" | cut -f 1 | cut -d" " -f 5-
```

Comment: THANKS, `cut` is what i was looking for

Comment: to get rid of the spaces at the end i used `xinput --list --short|grep "slave  pointer" | cut -f 1| cut -d" " -f 5-|sed 's/\s\+$//g'`

Comment: How do I use `cut` with the output of `ps`? see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79264/get-the-xth-argument-in-each-line

Comment: @rubo77 You don't really, you either set the `ps` output format or use `awk` as the answers to that question suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If it were the third element, that would be "SynPS/2", not "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"

The best you can achieve here is report what's before `id=` as it's the only thing that can identify where the device name ends.

```
xinput list | sed -n 's/^[ ⎜↳]*\(.*[^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]*id=.*slave  pointer.*/\1/p'
```

Or with GNU grep built with PCRE support (`-P` option):

```
xinput list | grep -Po '[^ ⎜↳].*?(?=\s+id=.*slave  pointer)'
```

Comment: The fields are separated by tabs so default cut will work.

Comment: OK, I can see when editing the question that they're there, but not in the _rendered_ version. I've edited my answer so that it works in either case.