# get the Xth argument in each line

Tags: text-processing, columns

I would like to get the second argument in a line of output. For example:

```
ps aux
```

gives me an output that contains the cpu-usage %CPU in the third column.

How can I filter the output so I have only that column?

I tried

```
ps aux | cut -f 3
```

but that's not working

see also: [Filtering the Xth element in a row?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57448/filtering-the-xth-element-in-a-row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a number of ways to accomplish this. Here's an example using `awk`:

`ps aux | awk '{print $3}'`

The `$3` argument to the `print` command will print the third field, by default delimited by a sequence of whitespace, of each line.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `ps` format options**

`ps` allows you to specify a custom output format.

```
ps ax o pcpu
```

The above command would return a single column of CPU usage data.

**Why `cut` doesn't work**

`cut`'s default delmiter is the tab character. `ps` uses spaces in its output, so you would have to use `cut -d' ' -f3` to select the third field (as `cut` sees it).

The problem with using cut is that it views anything adjacent to a delimiter as a field. Since `ps` prints multiple adjacent spaces between fields,

```
$ ps aux
...
para␣␣␣␣␣␣␣462␣␣0.0␣␣0.0␣␣13492␣␣1792␣tty1␣␣␣␣␣Ss+␣␣05:52␣␣␣0:00
root␣␣␣␣␣␣␣484␣␣1.8␣␣0.5␣137020␣45112␣?␣␣␣␣␣␣␣␣Ss␣␣␣05:52␣␣␣0:20
para␣␣␣␣␣␣␣490␣␣0.0␣␣0.0␣␣28072␣␣1708␣tty1␣␣␣␣␣S␣␣␣␣05:52␣␣␣0:00
...
$ ps aux | cut -d' ' -f3
...
␣
␣
␣
...
```

`cut` will print a column of spaces if you ask it for the third field. To make matters worse, the number of spaces that `ps` outputs between each field is not always uniform among the rows, so you can't just use `cut -d' ' -f12` You would end up with results like this:

```
...
4.6
0.0
0.0
␣
␣
0.0
0.1
␣
␣
␣
...
```

Comment: If you want to find a process in `ps aux` you can also use `pgrep` to just find the process nr.

Comment: Is there no possibility to tell cut to treat multiple spaces as one delimiter? then I could imagine a solution with cut too

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to tell cut to treat multiple spaces as one delimiter.